# html template is alright , but redirecting on the payments page is not working ... don't know why

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from carts.models import CartItem
from .forms import OrderForm
import datetime
from .models import Order

# Create your views here.

def payments(request):
    return render(request, 'orders/payments.html')

def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user
    
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()

    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('storx')

    delivery_charge = 40
    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0
    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    tax = (2 * total)/100    
    grand_total = total + tax + delivery_charge

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            data = Order()
            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            data.zipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.delivery_charge = delivery_charge
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr,mt,dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # 20230214
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()
            
            order = Order.objects.get(user=current_user, is_ordered=False, order_number=order_number)
            context = { 'order': order, 'cart_items': cart_items, 'total': total, 'tax': tax, 'delivery_charge': delivery_charge, 'grand_total': grand_total, }
            return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('checkout')
```

Answer (score 0):

in your current logic redirect to payment is only reached if form is not valid:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
        return redirect('checkout')
else:
    return redirect('checkout')
return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', context)
```

Comment: sorry for mistake , actually return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', context) this line is on whenever form is valid , but still it is not  redirecting to the payments page...

Comment: what means it does not redirect? did you check e.g. with a print that the form is actually valid?  is payments.html displayed in the browser? btw. you just render payments.html, there is no redirect so the url in the browser will not change if you expect that. Additionally you should add an else for form not valid to make the view always return a valid http response

Comment: yes , normally payments.html working whenever calling , but in this particuler case , if form is valid it should redirected to payments page and render payments.html with the context value .. but it is not working ... it simply running last line of code

Comment: please add html with the form to your question